# Regex with or and specific chars

Tags: regex

I'm not able to create a regex for a specific rule.

**The main rule :**

```
[FIX   -A or -D or -P with numbers and several times is possible     uppercase string]      :     string
```

**My tests :**

```
[FIX-A2569] TOTO : toto // should passed
[FIX-D256458-P4565] TOTO : toto // should passed
[FIX-D123123-A123123-A123123-P123123] TOTO : toto // should passed
[FIX-D123123-A123123-P123123] TOTO : toto // should passed
[FIX-D123123-A123123-A123123-P123123] TOTO : toto // should passed
[FIX-D123123-A123123A123123-P123123] TOTO : toto // should not passed
[FIX-D123123A123123A123123P123123] TOTO : toto // should not passed
[FIX-D123123-A123123A123123P123123] TOTO : toto // should not passed
```

**My REGEX :**

```
/\[FIX-A[0-9]+|-D[0-9]+|-P[0-9]+\] [A-Z0-9 _]+ : .+/g
```

**My result :**

Nothing passed.

Comment: Do not use `g` flag, the regex can be as below, or `^\[FIX(?:-[ADP]\d+)+] [A-Z0-9_]+ : .+`

Answer (score 1):

Just keep your regex short and use a tool to design it from left to right. This way you'll see when the expression gets stuck.

I would suggest `/\[FIX(-[ADP]\d+)+] [A-Z0-9]+ : .*/` as the regex:

https://regexr.com/72nd9

Use Regexr's explain-function to learn more about the regex.